# J2ME - Increasing record store size of emulator

Tags: java-me

is there a way to increase the record store size of the emulator (WTK2.5 and/or JavaME3.0) ?

So far, I haven't found any command line switches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via tool preferences in %WTK_HOME%/bin. Or by configuring exact device settings in xml files.

Comment: I don't think, I can specify the record store size in that way. Are you sure? What is the exact variable name for the record store?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/wtk-cldc-2.5.2-01/UserGuide-html/emulator.html#50626614_pgfId-49807 - storage settings screen shot of preferences tool.

Comment: I don't remember exact name of variable in xml settings but 99% that it exists.